# How can I remove search result page

Tags: wordpress

I made a new website, and I have a little problem. The site doesn't need any kind of search engine etc..
So I don't need the search result page. 
Is there maybe a way to make searching and search page redirect to home page?

So basically I want to redirect any user trying to access this page https://example.com/?s=  to home;

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could add the code below into your themes functions.php

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_s_to_homepage' );
function redirect_s_to_homepage(){
  if ( is_search() && ! empty ( $_GET['s'] )  ){
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url(), 301 );
    exit;
  }
}
```

It makes sure your loading search page and that there is a search variable set, and redirects you.

EDIT
The code above will work when there is an actual search query. example: ?s=something.

Since you are also wanting to redirect if there is no query, try the snippet below.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_s_to_homepage' );
function redirect_s_to_homepage(){
  if ( is_search() && isset( $_GET['s'] )  ){
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url(), 301 );
    exit;
  }
}
```

The first code was making sure ?s= wasn't empty. The edited code just makes sure ?s= is set.

Comment: I tried this but I'm still able to load https://example.com/?s= and I'm not getting redirected

Comment: I updated the answer with the slightly modified version that should work. I tested all variations of having a search term or not.

Answer (score 0):

We have an action hook called 'template_redirect' , for search query we can do following to achieve:

```
   function wm_search_redirect(){
    global $wp_query;   
    if( $wp_query->is_search) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        die;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wm_search_redirect' );
```

Please test it on non live site, as it is untested code just for idea.